Grafana - "no data" in dashboard
Grafana 11.1
Influx 2.4.1
I accquire data from Lumel ND30IoT into nodered via MQTT and then into influxdb. This part works fine. Notered, InfluxDB and Grafana are installed on industrial PC "EPC 1502".


But i have a problem with transfering them into grafana. When i create a new dashboard it says "no data".

That's how i configured it:

Is it a proper methodology?
Is data in Influx need to be downloaded in some special way or should it work as a real time data service?
Any help would be appreciated :smiley:
I thougt configuring Grafana connection would be enough.

Check your time range specified in Grafana, if there are no data point in Influx timestamped within that range then you'll get no results.
Try expanding the time range, remove the two Flux filter() statements, and see if there's anything actually in there - if there is then you can verify what's in your filters is correct too.
